# Docker compose fails to spin up new SQL Server but docker run is ok

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker compose:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU9-ubuntu-18.04"
    user: root
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "mysupersecretpassword"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - db:/var/opt/mssql
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

when I do a "docker compose up -d --build", the container starts but then dies with the message  unknown package id.

When I run it manually, it starts up:

```
PS C:\Users\me\widgets\server> docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=mysupersecretpassword' -e 'MSSQL_PID=Developer' --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU9-ubuntu-18.04
```

Can you tell me what I'm missing in the compose?

Host is Windows 10.

**EDIT 1**

Here's what happens when I do docker compose up:

```
PS C:\Users\me\widgets\server> docker compose up -d                                                                                       _
[+] Running 2/2
 - Network server_default  Created                                                                                                                   0.0s
 - Container server-db-1   Started                                                                                                                   0.4s
```

This is what I see in the logs for the container in docker desktop:

```
Attaching to server-db-1

server-db-1 | SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.

server-db-1 | This container is running as user root.

server-db-1 | Your master database file is owned by root.

server-db-1 | To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.

server-db-1 | ERROR: Unknown package id

server-db-1 | 

server-db-1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: Do not use --build flag and set a more 'secure' password. Works for me.

Comment: @VladyslavChaikovskyi i get the same results without the --build flag.  and yeah the password was just for this post.  we are using something secure.  I know this compose file used to work for me.  Just can't see what's changed / different

Comment: Try to clean up all the resources and relaunch :) You can use `docker-compose down -v` to remove named volumes. **But pay attention that data will be erased**.

Comment: @VladyslavChaikovskyi that did the trick.  thanks!